# asp.net send auto mails not workign on shared hosting server

Tags: asp.net

I want to send automatic email on certain condition from my application.And my application hosting account type is shared hosting.

I am using ASP.NET MVC2.0.

I have worked according to below article to send auto mails :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

its working on my local system but not my production server(shared hosted account).

Can any one suggest me the way to do it?

Comment: Define "not working."  In what way does it fail?  What do your debug logs tell you?

Comment: Have you definitely got everything configured properly for your shared host, e.g. outgoing SMTP servers with whatever authentication they need from their network?

Comment: I added log on my global.asax file.And i called RegisterCacheEntry() function in Application_Start() function of global.asax.But its not being called.Although its working well locally.